# Second transaction for same customer fails to increase transaction count

Tags: braintree

Dashboard --> Vault for a customer shows transaction count as `1` when even number of transaction for same customer is greater than `1`.

```
ckfmf6 Default  Visa 411111******1111   05/11/15    1
```

Code below creates customer and executes transaction.

```
TransactionRequest request = new TransactionRequest();
        request.customer()
                .firstName("Jenna")
                .lastName("Smith");
        request.creditCard()
                .number("4111111111111111")
                .expirationMonth("05")
                .expirationYear("2016")
                .cvv("100");
        request.billingAddress()
                .firstName("Jenna")
                .lastName("Smith")
                .postalCode("60622");
        request.amount(new BigDecimal("2"))
                .paymentMethodNonce("nonce-from-the-client")
                .options()
                .submitForSettlement(true)
                .storeInVaultOnSuccess(true)
                .done();
```

From result I get customerId - 129089.

Use the same customerId for second transaction.

```
TransactionRequest request = new TransactionRequest();
        request.customer()
                .customerId(129089)
                .firstName("Jenna")
                .lastName("Smith");
        request.creditCard()
                .number("4111111111111111")
                .expirationMonth("05")
                .expirationYear("2016")
                .cvv("100");
        request.amount(new BigDecimal("2"))
                .paymentMethodNonce("nonce-from-the-client")
                .options()
                .submitForSettlement(true)
                .done();
```

Number of transaction is still the same. What am I missing?

BTW what does `.paymentMethodNonce("nonce-from-the-client")` means? What is the idea behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it. Instead of passing to the object, pass the id in `customerId`.

```
TransactionRequest request = new TransactionRequest();
    request.customerId(129089);
    request.creditCard()
            .number("4111111111111111")
            .expirationMonth("05")
            .expirationYear("2016")
            .cvv("100");
    request.amount(new BigDecimal("2"))
            .paymentMethodNonce("nonce-from-the-client")
            .options()
            .submitForSettlement(true)
            .done();
```